# Exercise package and hyperlink exercise/solution : hide the empty solutions?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, exercises

I'm using the exercise package in order to manage exercises together with answers. In the following MWE, an hyperlink pointing to the associated answer is created at the beginning of each of them. If there is no solution, would it be possible to delete the previous hyperlink ? (see below exercise 2 for an example).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks = true,
            unicode    = true,
            colorlinks = true,
            urlcolor   = red,
            linkcolor  = red}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
%
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercice}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{%
    \noindent
    \textbf{
       \ExerciseName\quad\ExerciseHeaderNB\textit{\ExerciseHeaderTitle}\quad}%
    }
%Environnement exercice
\newenvironment{exo}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
\hfill \texttt{\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}}


}{\end{Exercise}}

\newenvironment{sol}
{\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
}
{\end{Answer}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{exo}
A
\end{exo}

\begin{sol}
ABCDE
\end{sol}

\begin{exo}
A
\end{exo}

\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your environment `exo` includes a hyperlink. If you don't mind using a new environment, just define a new environment without the hyperlink

```
\newenvironment{nhexo}[1][\unskip]{%
    \begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]


    }{\end{Exercise}}
```

Edited MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks = true,
            unicode    = true,
            colorlinks = true,
            urlcolor   = red,
            linkcolor  = red}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
%
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercice}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{%
    \noindent
    \textbf{
       \ExerciseName\quad\ExerciseHeaderNB\textit{\ExerciseHeaderTitle}\quad}%
    }
%Environment exercise
\newenvironment{exo}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
\hfill \texttt{\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}}


}{\end{Exercise}}

\newenvironment{nhexo}[1][\unskip]{%
    \begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]


    }{\end{Exercise}}

\newenvironment{sol}
{\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
}
{\end{Answer}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{exo}
A
\end{exo}

\begin{sol}
ABCDE
\end{sol}

\begin{nhexo}
A
\end{nhexo}

\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's. But would it be possible to find an automatic solution ? If I consider an other environment, I have to check one by one all the exercises without solution and change the associated environment name.

Comment: In the log file I can find the message : `LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `2-Answer' on page 1 undefined on input line 44.`. A solution would be to add a boolean test on the reference X-Answer, but I don't know if it's possible.